# Error while full update pip packages

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

While pip update all packages with command

```
pip freeze --local | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs pip install -U
```

Pip print error with **vboxapi**

```
  Downloading/unpacking vboxapi
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement vboxapi
  Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external vboxapi to allow).
  Some insecure and unverifiable files were ignored (use --allow-unverified vboxapi to allow).
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for vboxapi
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/rmuhamedgaliev/.pip/pip.log
```

Can i say pip ignore vboxapi while update?
I tried commands

```
pip freeze --local | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs pip install -U -I
pip freeze --local | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs pip install -U -I --allow-external vboxapi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can ignore the `vboxapi` package like this.

```
grep -Pv '^(?:\-e|vboxapi\=)'
```

- The `-P` flag tells grep to use perl-compatible regex.
- The `-v` flag says to only list those which do *not* match the regex that follows.
- The regex matches lines that begin with `-e` or `vboxapi=`

---

**Full example for what you want to accomplish:**

```
pip freeze --local | grep -Pv '^(?:\-e|vboxapi\=)' | cut -d = -f 1 | xargs -n1 pip install -U;
```